# Sharing observable across instances of the same component

Tags: knockout.js

I have a component which is a drop down menu (Actually a bootstrap button menu). The 'dropdown' gets it's values by doing an AJAX call to the server and parsing a JSON string.

I need this button in multiple places on the page however I need new instances of the component each time as I have to pass in the calling viewmodel to add some data to it.

Obviously every time I include this button the component does an ajax call to get it's values meaning there are n number of AJAX calls to the server. Is there anyway I can just do one Ajax call and propagate it to every instance of the component?

Button component

```
        function AddElement(params) {
        this.options = ko.observableArray();
        var self = this;
        var section = params.section;

            $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/test", function (data) {
                elementOptions = data;
                self.options(data);
            });

            this.addElement = function (data) {
                section.formElements.push(data);
            };

    }
```

So the question is how can I achieve this or is there a better way to implement this kind of functionality in KO (i.e not components)

Thanks

David

Comment: Do the loading in the parent component and pass the data to each child component.

Comment: It's a bad idea to have your UI layer doing data access. An alternative solution would be to create a loader class that is responsible for doing the AJAX call and possibly caching it.

Comment: Move the AJAX  call outside the AddElement function, and have it populate a local array. Within AddElement, copy data from that local array instead of making the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Do the loading in some common parent of your component and pass in the observable array.

```
function AddElement(params) {
    var self = this,
        section = params.section,
        options = params.options;
}
```

Option 2: Pass a loader object to your component.

```
function AddElement(params) {
    var self = this,
        section = params.section,
        loader = params.loader; //All 'AddElement' components get passed the same instance of the loader

    this.options = ko.observableArray();
    loader.load(function (data) { //The loader is responsible for doing the AJAX once and only once.
        elementOptions = data;
        self.options(data);
    });
}
```